# Agile testing main goals

Tags: agile-testing, qa-role

What are the main goals of agile testing? I think it is plan, develop, test, review, deploy (shippable product). The primary goal would be to test until we have a shippable product. Correct me if Im wrong. Thanks

Comment: This is a good question but unfortunately  a little broad.  It will be hard to upvote and downvote "good" and "bad" answers.  Please scope down with from what perspective.  Agile is about developing software that meets users needs but following the principles in the Agile Manifesto and implementation is generally somewhat different in every situation.  Some things should remain constant.  Too many to list here in this q as a comment.

Comment: I would like to add that when you say "The primary goal would be to test until we have a shippable product.", is false, because you can't make a shippable product just by testing it. Primary goal is always the software itself.

Comment: Isn't the main goal of any product to plan, develop, test, review, and deploy?

Comment: @trashpanda, yes and no. It's about semantics, would you agree? Working software is the primary goal and there are many ways to accomplish this. Agile testing is done with short feedback loops in mind and to deliver more value faster to the customers.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Agile Manifesto](https://agilemanifesto.org/principles.html):

> Working software is the primary measure of progress.

Therefore, the primary goal of testing for developers with agile mindset is to deliver more software that satisfy the user needs.

OBS: It may seem obvious, but it means that **anything else** is not the primary goal - and if you just achieve secondary goals, you have failed. It includes documentation, and even **testing itself**: If you have done 100 hours more of exploratory testing, but the product was not delivered: Failure.

Comment: this seems like a great answer but it is cut in the middle, could you fix it ?

Comment: Thank you Rsf, completed - it was just few missing words :D